# How can I show my application description in admin web-console (wildfly)?

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, web.xml

I want to show some description for my app.war in web-console in wildfly. But I can't do this.
I tried to use tag  in web.xml but this doesn't work.
How can I do this?